# Meaning of Interval with logical conjunction

Tags: logic, stochastic-processes

while studying with a script I came across an interval which I do not understand:

"For $S,T>0$, the processes $X^S$ and $X^T$ are distinguishable on $[0,S \land T]$"

How can I imagine the interval $[0,S \land T]$? I think I would understand a different way of writing it

Comment: [Join and meet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet)? If so the *meet* $S \land T$ is simply the lower one.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA yes I think you are right, so it means $S \land T = inf(\{S,T\})$